# google maps Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have App I'm working on it's working as good before I Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects , not it's give me a error `google maps Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type`

and map working good in IOS with same google api key that i used in android

I have did `flutter clean` more than one and uninstall app and use different emulator, the error is same

**androidManifest.xml**

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="come.example.appid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- Speech To Text configration -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <!-- Geolocator Configration Start -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Geolocator Configration end -->
    <!-- Local Notification -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <!-- Local Notification -->

    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="appname"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <!-- Google Maps -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
             android:value="APIKeyyyyyyyyyyyy-xxxxxxxx"/>

        <!-- Google Maps -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

        <!-- Facebook Configration Start -->
        <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/> -->


        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <!-- FCM Configration start -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- FCM Configration end -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Facebook Configration end -->

        <!-- Local Notification -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specify that the launch screen should continue being displayed -->
            <!-- until Flutter renders its first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <!-- Theme to apply as soon as Flutter begins rendering frames -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**the error is**

> E/flutter ( 8262): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error,
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of
>   unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/google_maps E/flutter ( 8262):
>     at
>   io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:91)
>   E/flutter ( 8262):    at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
>   E/flutter ( 8262):    at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
>   E/flutter ( 8262):    at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
>   E/flutter ( 8262):

Comment: I face the same problem, i comes from code. add ur code the file have GoogleMap widget. Maybe I can help u

Answer (score 23):

I have also got the same error for android but my code works after following these steps:

1. Clean App data & Uninstall the current app.
2. Run flutter clean & flutter build.
3. Run Your App again

Answer (score 11):

Your `minSdkVersion` must be greater than 20

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter run
```

Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Replace in `MainActivity.kt` the next import:
`import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity`
for:
`import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity`

This solve the problem!